# Does the kernel propagates SIGKILL to the process or kills it immediately?

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix

I'm currently learning how signals really works in POSIX-systems. Signals such as `SIGTERM` can be caught and handled with custom handlers, this means that the kernel propagates the signal to the process itself. On the other hand `SIGKILL` is not catchable and cannot be handled firstly because it is its main purpose - kill the process. But I'm wondering does this means that the `SIGKILL` is not even propagated to the process ? I mean if the users will send kill -9 to some process using terminal the kernel will immediately purge that process without even forwarding the signal to it, or the signal will still be forwarded to the process but with the exception that we cannot add a custom handler to it?
 Sorry, if you consider this question dummy! I'm just starting with POSIX systems

Comment: What would it mean to "forward a signal" which cannot be handled? Please phrase the answer in pseudocode.

Comment: I mean maybe C have some default `SIGKILL` handlers that cannot be overwritten! I this case signal still have to be forwarded

Comment: But what would such a handler do? The process is not allowed to respond in any way ("cannot be caught, blocked or ignored" according to the docs). Anyway, the answer is no. The kernel kills the process. .

Comment: okay, got it ! Thank you

Comment: Strictly speaking, posix considers the signal "delivered" when the process is killed. (Posix doesn't use the word "propagated"). The delivery is fatal. No handler is invoked.

Comment: Besides, the `signal()` or `sigaction()` function call to set up a signal handler for `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP` would return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

some signals can catch and we name those catchable signals and some are uncatchable. The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

You can see a complete list of signals and appropriate action [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).